# char *str[ ] pass by reference not working

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am passing a char *str[] in help function and then adding contents to it but in main function its values are unchanged.

From main i am calling letterCombinations function and it calls help function 
In help I am editing valuees of char * str[] wwhihc are changed there but are not reflected in letter Combinations function

Please help me why is it not working

```
help(char *str[],char* curr,int index,char* digits,char** a,int *k)
        {
            if(strlen(curr)==strlen(digits))
            {
                printf("%d",*k);
                 str[*k]=(char*)malloc(strlen(digits)+1);
                 str[*k]=curr;
                printf("%s %s %d\n",curr,str[*k],*k);

                *k=*k+1;

                return ;
            }

            int i;

            char* loop=a[digits[index]-'0'];

            int l=strlen(loop);
            for(i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
                curr[index]=loop[i];

                help(str,curr,index+1,digits,a,k);
                curr[index]='\0';
            }
        }
  char** letterCombinations(char* digits, int* returnSize) {
            char *str[100];
              int i=0;
            char* curr=malloc(sizeof(strlen(digits)+1));
            char** a=(char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
          int siz=0;
            a[0]="";
            a[1]="";
            a[2]="abc";
            a[3]="def";
            a[4]="ghi";
            a[5]="jkl";
            a[6]="mno";
            a[7]="pqrs";
            a[8]="tuv";
            a[9]="wxyz";

            help(str, curr, 0, digits,a,&siz);

            printf("  %d",siz);
            for(i=0;i<siz;i++)
            {
                printf(" s   %s",str[i]);
            }
           // *returnSize=siz;
            return str;




        }
```

Comment: `char *str[100]` declares an array of 100 pointers, each pointing to nowhere, as they are not initialized. That is hardly what you wanted.

Comment: I am allocating memory in help function str[*k]=(char*)malloc(strlen(digits)+1);

Comment: `return str;` : `str` is local variable.

Comment: isn't passing a array  always by reference so changes should be made in char * str[] itself without any need of return

Comment: Skag, ok, but in the line after the `malloc`, you overwrite the pointer to the memory with `curr`, so it is lost. Afterwards, you are changing curr when you think you lare changing str[*k]. Maybe you mean `strcpy(str[*k],curr)` there?

Comment: Aganju please explain more about overwrite of memory, all I want to do is copy contents of curr to str[\*k]

Comment: @skag After malloc, when you do `str[*k] = curr`, it's not assigning the string to that dynamic piece of memory. It's making `str[*k]` point to `curr`, and the dynamic piece of memory was never used causing a leak. You have to use `strcpy` or better yet `strncpy` to copy the string from `curr` into `str[*k]`

Comment: so what is the best practice to get contents of curr in str[\*k] should I use strcpy(str[\*k],curr)

Comment: `strcpy` will work if you're careful on your lengths of your string. I recommend `strncpy` since it limits the amount of characters being copied.

Comment: Thanks Aganju and Miket25

Comment: Whenever you have a function with 6 arguments (you probably should not have a function with 6 arguments), you should _document_ what the arguments are and how they are used. It is difficult to read such undocumented code.

Comment: will take care of documentation next time thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you compile your code you should see warnings such as:

```
warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
warning C4100: 'returnSize' : unreferenced formal parameter
```

returning address of local variable or temporary is the warning which explains your behaviour.

In your code:

```
char** letterCombinations(char* digits, int* returnSize) {
    char *str[100];
   ...
    return str;
}
```

You create an array on the stack, str.  When you return from letterCombinations, the variable goes out of scope and the stack memory location gets cleaned up.  ie the memory address used by str is no longer valid.

You could change so that caller passes in their own char* variable which would fix this issue.  Alternatively, you could malloc str and then when you return from the function, the memory location still exists.  But the caller would have to free the memory location - which is messy.

After fixing that ... then move onto the next bug.

The next thing I notice is that in the help function you have:

```
if (strlen(curr) == strlen(digits))
```

but curr is not initialised.  Fix that next.  then move onto your next bug.

You should step through each line thinking through how your variables will be populated in each line.

Comment: yes that str part was wrong now I am using  char** str=(char**)malloc(10000*sizeof(char*));